# Queued Timebase workflow not firing after scheduled date

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have a time-based workflow that should have fired by now.  I can see the entry still sitting int the queue.
[image]

It's now 15 minutes past when it was scheduled to fire.  Wondering why it hasn't fired yet?

Comment: I just re-checked as soon as I submitted this post and it had fired.  I guess it take up to 15 minutes?  Or maybe they only fire on 15 min intervals?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The time based workflow processor only runs once every fifteen minutes, starting from the time the processor starts. For example, if the server comes up at three minutes past the hour, it will run at 3, 18, 33, and 48 after the hour.

Comment: Not that it matters, but what do you mean the server comes up/processor starts?   Assuming this is something inside the salesforce black box that runs time based workflows?

Comment: @NSjonas That's basically the idea. When the salesforce stack is shut down (e.g. for maintenance), everything comes to a halt. After the stack is brought back up (or at some point during that sequence), the time-based workflow process starts up, which basically looks something like `while(true) { Thread.sleep(900000); processPendingItems(); }` (over-simplified, of course). There are other processes that follow this rule, too, like Escalation rules.

Answer (score 0):

Time-dependent actions aren’t executed independently. They’re grouped into a single batch that starts executing within one hour after the first action enters the batch. Apex triggers that fire as a result of time-dependent actions may get executed in a single batch or independently. 
[See official doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5)